# How I include oracle client in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, linq, ado.net

I have a DAL.CS class in App_Code.I am using oracle Database.I also added OracleClient refrence in Refrence folder but I am getting following error
    CS0234: The type or namespace name 'OracleClient' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?).How I solved this problem

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OracleClient;


     namespace SchoolsManagementSystem
    {
      public class DAL
      {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracleconnect"].ConnectionString;
        private OracleConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var conString =       System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracleconnect"];
            string strConnString = conString.ConnectionString;
            return new OracleConnection(strConnString);
        }
        public string AunthicateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            using (OracleConnection con = GetConnection())
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM AuthenticateUser(@UserName, @Password)", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", "username");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", "password");

                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                string str = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
               // Response.Write(str.ToString());

                return str;
            }
        }

    }
  }
```

What does following error mean.I added refrence of Oracle client.
    Source Error:
    Line 5:  using System.Configuration;
    Line 6:  using System.Data;
    Line 7:  using System.Data.OracleClient;
    Line 8:
    Line 9:

```
Source File: d:\c#\SchoolsManagementSystem\SchoolsManagementSystem\App_Code\DAL.cs    Line: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Microsoft Oracle Client.  Even Microsoft says not to use it.  Use Oracle's ODP.net or devArt dotConnect (there is a free version).  The Microsoft driver was dropped after .NET 2.0, and for good reason.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

The majority of your code will not change.

Comment: after install ODP.net what namespace I used?I mean ODP.OracleClient

Comment: using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;